# How to make a list of pairs from facts in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Assuming I have some facts like the following

```
person(jessica,19,usa).
person(james,18,uk).
person(eric,34,italy).
person(jake,24,france).
```

how can I create a predicate that creates a large list of pairs of all the names and their corresponding country like so:

```
?-filter(L).
L=[(jessica,usa),(james,uk),(eric,italy),(jake,france)]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @lambda.xy.x I tried doing 
filter([H|T]):-
person(X,_,Y),H is (X,Y),filter(T).

however the interpreter told me that I'm doing something that is not a function.

Comment: `is` is about mathematical evaluation (like `H is 1+2`), using the equality `H = (X,Y)` should do what you expect. You will run into a second problem, but this should get you a bit further.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Thank you , I didn't realise that, I see now that I'm running into an infinite "loop", my base case should be that there is no longer persons left to insert in the list, however I don't know how can I work my way around this.

Comment: You could add an argument that tracks what you have seen (a so called accumulator) and you require that the result from the recursion is not yet tracked.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x I reach this so far : 

`filter([H|T]):-
filter([H|T],[]).

filter([H|T],Acc):-
person(X,_,Y),not(member(person(X,_,Y),Acc)),
H = (X,Y),
filter(T,[person(X,_,Y)|Acc]).`

however I feel like I'm missing something, maybe in the concept of accumulator itself?

Comment: btw alternatively there's also `setof/3` (the path i'm leading you to implements something in that line)

Comment: (I have to go to bed, I'll continue in the morning - the pointer to setof should help you get a result fast at least)

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Thank you for turning my attention to setof :) , I have reached a point where now I'm very close to my wanted answer with this code `filter(L):-
findall(L1,setof((X,Y),person(X,_,Y),L1),L).`

However, it is making it a list of lists, I understand why it is doing so, so I need to ask, is there a way to convert lists to atoms first?

Comment: You don't want the `setof` inside the `findall`. Get rid of that. Use `findall` or use `setof`, but not both. E.g., `findall( (X,Y), person(X, _, Y), L).` is all you need.

Comment: @lurker Thank you so much! But can you please explain to me briefly what is the difference between findall and setof? I had a misconception that they did the same thing but one with sorted results and the other is not, setof gets one set of the answer but findall appends all answers together? Am I on the right track?

Comment: `setof` sorts and eliminates duplicates.

Comment: @lurker I do not get how `setof` sorts, it doesn't get all the options in one list either way.

Comment: @Angelrina you could download the source code to see its inner workings (I'm not familiar with them) but I assume it does an insertion sort (perhaps) with the list as it creates it. At least that would be a typical way to do it. Maybe I'm not sure what you mean by "how" in this context.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is this one:

```
?- bagof((P,C), Age^person(P,Age,C), People).
People = [(jessica, usa),  (james, uk),  (eric, italy),  (jake, france)].
```

This gives you the same result as `findall/3`, because `findall/3` implicitly assumes existential quantification on all variables not present in the template (`(P,C)` is the template). In your case you only have one, the age variable. Notice what happens if you don't include that:

```
?- bagof((P,C), person(P,_,C), People).
People = [(james, uk)] ;
People = [(jessica, usa)] ;
People = [(jake, france)] ;
People = [(eric, italy)].
```

What happened here? The value of the second parameter was the same across each solution because we didn't inform `bagof/3` that we didn't care what it was bound to or even if it was bound to just one thing. This property of `bagof/3` and `setof/3` (but not `findall/3`) sometimes turns out to be surprisingly useful, so I tend to prefer using `bagof/3` over `findall/3` if I only need to mark a variable or two.

It's more obvious if we add another person the same age to the database:

```
person(janet,18,australia).

?- bagof((P,C), person(P,Age,C), People).
Age = 18,
People = [(james, uk),  (janet, australia)] .

?- bagof((P,C), person(P,_,C), People).
People = [(james, uk),  (janet, australia)] ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `person/3` is ground and terminates, you can implement it without setof as:

```
notin(_, []).
notin(X, [Y|Ys]) :-
    dif(X,Y),
    notin(X,Ys).

lt_list(_, []).
lt_list(X, [Y|Ys]) :-
    X @< Y,
    lt_list(X,Ys).

f( [ Name-Location | Rest], Acc) :-
    person(Name, _, Location),
    lt_list( Name-Location, Acc ),
    f(Rest, [Name-Location | Acc]).
f( [], Acc) :-
    \+ (person(Name,_,Location), notin(Name-Location,Acc)).
```

When we query `f`, we get our solutions:

```
?- f(Xs,[]).
Xs = [jessica-usa, james-uk, jake-france, eric-italy] ;
false.
```

I used `X-Y` instead of `(X,Y)` for better readability. The predicate `notin` describes an element that is not contained in a list and `lt_list` describes an element that is smaller than anything in the list by the standard term order.

The idea is that the first rule generates persons that I have not seen yet. Using the term order makes sure that we don't generate all permutations of the list (try replacing `lt_list` by `notin` to see what happens). The second rule makes sure we only terminate if there are no more solutions to generate. Be aware that the rule contains negation, which can have some unwanted side-effects. Most of them are filtered out by only looking at ground terms, but I have not thought well, how bad the impact is in this solution.